# What does 社会 mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

社会generally means society, community.

But what is its real meaning in the following cases: 1. 社会力量办学；2.此为公交专用车道，社会车辆不得驶入; 3.走出校门，走进社会？

My understanding is: 1. schools run by private sector; 2. this is the track for public transportation only, private traffic is denied. So 社会 means private?

As for No. 3, I think it means I leave the school and enter the society, but isn't school part of the society?

Comment: jukuu:1,2.社会力量:nongovernmental sectors,(all) social sectors (referring to enterprises, institutions, mass organizations and individual citizens) Non-State
3.走出校门，走进社会？going into Society (world of business),private sector:个体私营经济 individual and private sector (economy),私营工业部门,私营机构 .Private sector

Comment: 社会 here is opposite to govenment (国营), i.e. business / company.

Answer (score 1):

> 1. 社会力量办学；

社会 VS 国家 or 政府

> 2.此为公交专用车道，社会车辆不得驶入;

社会 means any 车辆 that not from 公交部门

> 3.走出校门，走进社会？

Here is the typical usage of 社会.

Most of organizations was run by government before 改革开放, these organizations  are usually called 机关, 单位 or 组织 etc...

If a man does not work in that kind of organizations, he lives in 社会, he is not 组织中的人.

For example, 社会人 is an interesting words, in some situation it means they do not have a formal job, they have complex relations with different kind of people... it is very complex, I did not prepare for this term.

And 学校 is opposite of 社会 in China.

社会 is not only society in China, it has some negative meanings from history periods.

Comment: Thanks. By the way, what kind of job is a formal job? And informal job? As in a 黑社会?

Comment: @NanningYouth  Labor Contract, insurance,  holiday, weekend... 社会人 is not 黑社会, but 底层社会 if we look at from a high level. Depending on the context, 社会 might be a neutral words or including 上层社会.

Answer (score 0):

社会, in those contexts, refers to the public reference to/opposite the certain independent group.

社会力量办学: means gathering the 力量（including money, labor, etc) from the public to 办学, not from the government.

社会车辆 refers to any type of vehicles from the public. It excludes the special purpose of vehicles,  公交 in the above context.

走出校门，走进社会. Here school is considered as a small community, while 社会 refers to the more wider 'community'. It implies students would face more when entering into 社会.

I hope I get this clear.

Comment: If as you say it is a school of the public, then it is a public school, but in fact it is a private school, isn't it?

Comment: I may not have a good word in English. Basically, 社会力量 refers to anyone except the government. (that's what I meant by "the public"). In order to understand 社会......, you should get "a small special group" to compare first and then 社会 will be "the larger common group". "government", "公交" and "校门" are considered to be small special groups in the above cases, while 社会 refers to everything excluding those small special groups. Hope you could understand.

Comment: It is not that you had said anything wrong. But I think there is confusion in the wording by the user. If everybody has no problem understanding the meaning, it is OK. We simply need to learn it and use the same next time.